# AWS SES - Check which verified email is causing the limits to exceed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have configured my AWS SES account to have an email sending quota as follows. But given the last 24 hours, this quota has exceeded, causing SES to reject sending emails.

```
Sending Quota:  send 127500 emails per 24 hour period
Quota Used: 100% as of 2019-10-08 10:06 UTC+5:30
```

I have around 5 verified emails, connected to different services. Is there a way to check which email address has caused the quota to be exceeded? (May be with a different permission for my role)

**PS**: *Checking application logs of each service is not an option.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to see the separated statistics but you can configure SNS to get the notification for each mail. See the [Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/configure-sns-notifications.html).

You can configure the notifications for each mail from the console > email addresses > select an email > see details > notification > edit configuration. Before doing this, you should have an SNS topic and just select that topic. From the notification, you can save them to DB or somewhere, count the number of emails where the email is sent from what email.